# RAML resource accept multiple enums

Tags: rest, api-design, raml

I have a `details` trait with defined `enums`

```
details:
   queryParams:
      detail:
         type: string
         enum: [small, big, categories, box]
```

When I query endpoint, which uses this trait, `example.com/api?detail=small,big`, I get API validation error.

How to define `enum` so that I could query for `example.com/api?detail=small` and `example.com/api?detail=small,big` and `example.com/api?detail=small,big,small` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

For that use-case you can use a trait passing in a list of fields of allowed values like so:

```
#%RAML 1.0
---
title: test
baseUri: https://mocksvc.qax.mulesoft.com/mocks/73ff2db5-abbf-4cad-aab1-80f6da9d6055
version: v2
protocols: [ HTTP ]
mediaType: application/json

traits:
  sparsable:
    queryParameters:
      detail?:
        type: string
        pattern: (<<fieldset>>),?

/api:
  displayName: api
  get:
    is: [ sparsable: { fieldset: small|big|categories|box } ]
```

kudos: https://medium.com/raml-api/arrays-in-query-params-33189628fa68